# LOOK - else if statement: where do i put it

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, task, eclipse-kepler

I don't know where to put my ELSE statement, if I put it in the for loop, after the IF statement, it repeats the thing inside the else statement loads of times. But if I put whats in ELSE statement that I want to be outputted, eg 'sorry this registration plate couldn't be found' outside the FOR loop then it outputs when i dont want it to.

```
    else // or 
            {
                // this code reads a file in
                String full="";
                try { FileReader reader = new FileReader("address.txt"); // new file reader to read in a file called address
                BufferedReader OwnerDetails = new BufferedReader(reader); // reads in the file efficiently

                String line; // assigning a string
                while ((line = OwnerDetails.readLine()) != null) { // reads in all file
                    full=full+line;

                }
                reader.close(); // the reader close, it finishes reading it in
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //System.out.println(full); // reads in whole file, and outputs it, used to check if the file had been written in
                    // it is commented out once program is finished, but is used when testing
                String[] details = full.split(","); // splits up info into arrays

                String searchword=registration; // searchword is set as the registration plate entered
                for (int i=0;i<details.length-2;i=i+1) 
                {
                    if(searchword.equals(details[i])) // if the search word is in the file
                    {
                        System.out.println("Name: " +details[i-1]); // outputs name
                        System.out.println("Registration: "+details[i]); // outputs reg plate again 
                        System.out.println("Address Line 1: "+details[i+1]); // outputs address
                        System.out.println("Address Line 2: "+details[i+2]); // outputs address line 2

                        fw2.write(details[i-1]+","); // separates the details when writing in to the file
                        fw2.write(details[i]+",");
                        fw2.write(details[i+1]+",");
                        fw2.write(details[i+2]+",");
                        fw2.write(speed+"/n");
                        fw2.close(); // file writer closes

                    }
                }

                System.out.println("The numberplate entered could not be found in the file, sorry."); // outputted if registration is not found
            }
```

**the task is to search for a registration plate in a file, and if its not in the file, then it should output that its not in the file.**

> the output of the code above is: `the speed the car was driving at was: 39.47 mph
>   Name: Adam Davies
>   Registration: AA12ASD
>   Address Line 1: 1 New Road
>   Address Line 2: Northfleet
>   The numberplate entered could not be found in the file, sorry.`

Comment: I recommend going through this first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: @Rakesh  - I still don't understand, I read another question, and they said put the else statement outside the for loop, but that makes it output everytime, do I need a Boolean?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what your application needs to do, because no one here knows the context. I am not sure what you meant when you said `using the else outside the for loop`. An `else` condition can never exist without an `if`, and it has to always succeed the `if` statement. Otherwise, it will not compile. I do not know how your code even compiled when you put the else "outside the `for` loop". Perhaps there was a pre-existing `if` condition without an else?.

Comment: do you want to see my code? I really need help, I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: The point is that your question doesn't really make sense. Refer this link on how to ask a question that is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: okay sorry, ill change it

Comment: hi,  ive changed it now, does it make sense? @Rakesh

Comment: It is still not clear, however, from what I understood, I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So the way I would do it is I would add a boolean checking if the details have been found.

start off with making it at the very beginning and set it to `false`.
then when

```
if(searchword.equals(details[i]))
```

make the boolean `true`.
after the for loop, check if the boolean is `false`, and if it is `false`, print your sorry this registration plate couldn't be found

a simple example following looks like this:

```
boolean yes = false;
    for (int i=0;i<details.length-2;i=i+1){
        if(searchword.equals(details[i])){
            System.out.println("Name: " +details[i-1]);
            yes = true;
        }
    }
    if (!yes){
        System.out.println("sorry this registration plate couldn't be found")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I gathered it correctly, the intent of the code is to find whether a particular registration number exists in the text file. For this, you are reading the entire file content into a string and splitting it on `,`. And then using a `for loop` to iterate through the entire array and look for a particular *registration number* that you have, ie, `searchword`.

For the record, I'm not entirely convinced with the way in which you have implemented it (could have been way better, which I won't touch upon). However, going with the way that you have implemented, the problem with your approach is that you are performing an operation of searching for a `key` in the `for loop`, and try to do both the `if-else` part within the loop itself.

This is how you could do what you need.

```
    String a = "Hello,World,Foo,Bar,abc,def,ghi,Hello1,World1,Foo1,Bar1,abc,def,ghi";
    String[] b = a.split(",");
    String searchWord = "abc";

    boolean hasSearchWord = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if(b[i].equals(searchWord)) {
            hasSearchWord = true;
            System.out.println("Word found");
            // Print whatever you need
            System.out.println(b[i - 1]);
            System.out.println(b[i]);
            System.out.println(b[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    if(!hasSearchWord) {
        System.out.println("Word not found");
    }
```

When searching for `abc`, this will produce

```
Word found
Bar
abc
def
Word found
Bar1
abc
def
```

When searching for `duh`, this will produce

```
Word not found
```